# Rest api to get sharepoint version

Tags: rest

I have 2 different programs that are built on the Microsoft client DLLs:

1. Version 2010 - Uses the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`
2. Version 2013 - Uses the Microsoft CSOM 2013 dll.

I am given a web URL that could be either 2010 or 2013 sharepoint URL but I don't know which.

How can I make a simple REST api call to determine SharePoint version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply calling the SharePoint root site or any other SharePoint site for that reason you get the versionnumber in the responseheader. ("MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices") This is no a reliable way of finding out the real buildversion but enough to determine which version of SharePoint.

SharePoint 2010 = 14.x, SharePoint 2013 = 15.x and SharePoint 2016 = 16.x

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try Contextinfo API call to get the version of SharePoint.
Kindly revert back if you need any further information.

**Update** 
I have used the [SP Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd?hl=en) Chrome extension to get Contextinfo using POST method, but for some wired reasons same is not working with POSTMAN

Ref
[POSTMan failing to get Contextinfo](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145892/postman-rest-call-to-api-contextinfo-failing/148438)

All the best.

Comment: Tried it. blank response 
POST {SPURL}/_api/contextinfo
Header: Accept application/json;odata=verbose

returns empty string

Comment: I tried it with SharePoint REST Client (Powered by SharePoint Plex) which returns the library version

Comment: Yes it works on SP 2013. but if you read my question, i need this to work on sharepoint 2010 too.